# Fragment transaction remove

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment, which I add with a tag like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment,fragment_tag).commit();
```

At some point, in another fragment, I need to remove this fragment so I call:

```
fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment_tag);
if(fragment != null && fragment.isAdded())
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

In theory, the next time I call `findFragmentByTag()` for the fragment I just removed, I should get a null, however, the next time i call this:

```
fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment_tag);
if(fragment != null)
```

The if statement is true so it actually finds a fragment with that tag!

My question is, how do I **COMPLETELY** remove a fragment?

Take in consideration that the fragment to be removed may not be in the top of the backstack, that meaning that `popBackStack()` is not a solution.

Comment: The trick is that the fragment you find is `isRemoving`, so you can just ignore it then.

Comment: @Ricardo Did you solve this problem ? I'm facing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the fragment, it might still be in the fragment manager back stack, so to completely remove it you have to remove if from the fragment manager back stack, so you have to pop it out of the back stack by calling the fragmentManager.popBackStack(String, int) method...

Check out the method 
[Fragment Manager pop back stack method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Check my edited question. The fragment may not be in the top of the backstack

Comment: did you try it? if you want it removed immediately you can call popackStackImmeditely();

Comment: I did try that. And i have searched over SOF which present this solution but that does not help my case

Comment: and the fragment was not declared in the activity layout file?

Comment: Let's say I have 5 fragments, which are added to the activity, the fragment I intend to remove is not in the top of the backstack. All of them are added in the activity, each one with its own tag

Comment: @Ricardo Did you solve this problem ? I'm facing the same one.

Answer (score -1):

```
int index = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().indexOf(oldfragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().set(index, null);
```

Comment: Please mention something about how this will resolve the issue or what this will do